$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}})$ is not a cyclic extension of degree 4 over $\mathbb{Q}$

Let $D \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a squarefree integer and let $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ be a nonzero rational number. Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}})$ cannot be a cyclic extension of degree 4 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$x^4 - a^2D = (x^2 + a\sqrt{D})(x^2 - a\sqrt{D})$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ with roots $\pm \sqrt{a\sqrt{D}}$ and $\pm i\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}}$ but from here I'm unsure of how to continue. Is it enough to say $\sigma : \sqrt{a\sqrt{D}} \mapsto -\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}}$ and $\tau : i \mapsto -i$ are two different degree 2 automorphisms? It's also been mentioned that the roots of a factor can only map to a root of the same factor, hence 2 degree 2 automorphisms, but I'm not sure why (1, specifically, I don't know anything about embeddings).
I guess I could also suppose there is an automorphism of order 4. The only option then is that $\pi : \sqrt{a\sqrt{D}} \mapsto i\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}}$, but then $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is fixed by $\pi$, so $\pi$ is actually of order 2..?

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}})$ is not necessarily the splitting field of $x^4 - a^2 D$; you have not adjoined all roots of this polynomial, only one of them. (Indeed, this field is definitely not Galois when $a$ and $D$ are positive, since some of the roots are complex but $\sqrt{a\sqrt{D}}$ is real.)

It's unclear $\sigma, \tau, \pi$ actually define automorphisms, also unclear whether they are different. There are a lot of details to be filled.
Let $\alpha = \sqrt{a\sqrt D}$. Assume $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q$ is a cyclic extension of degree $4$. Since $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $x^4-a^2D=0$, and the irredicuble polynomial of $\alpha$ must be of degree $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=4$, this is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$. Therefore, there is a unique field automorphism that sends $\alpha$ to one of the roots of $x^4-a^2D=0$. (This shows your $\sigma$ and $\pi$ are well-defined under the cyclic extension assumption, but not so clear about $\tau$.)
Let $g(\alpha)=a\alpha$ be a generator of the Galois group, where $a\in\{-1, \pm i\}$. If $a=-1$, then $g^2(\alpha)=g(a\alpha)=ag(\alpha)=a^2\alpha=\alpha$, hence $g^2$ is already the identity automorphism. Therefore $a=\pm i$. (This justifies your $\pi$ is reasonable, but definitely not the "only" one, as the cyclic group of order $4$ contains two generators. But still, it's unclear how $\pi$ acts on $i$.)
Therefore $g:\alpha\mapsto i\alpha$ and $h:\alpha\mapsto -i\alpha$ are two elements of order $4$ and they are inverses of each other. Hence $$\alpha=(h\circ g)(\alpha)=h(i\alpha)=h(i)h(\alpha)=h(i)\cdot(-i\alpha) \\ \Longrightarrow h(i)=i \text{ and } g(i) = h^{-1}(i)=i$$
(Finally we justified your claim about your $\pi$.)
But this implies the fixed field of $g$ (hence the whole Galois group) is not $\Bbb Q$, but at least $\Bbb Q[i]$, so $\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ is not even Galois, a contradiction.
This proves a stronger statement the Galois group of $x^4-b$ cannot be cyclic of order $4$, without assuming $b$ has a special form. I guess the author of the exercise expected you to observe that the extension $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ has at least two subextensions of degree $2$: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt a)$. It's easy to show they are indeed subextensions of degree $2$, but a bit headache to show they are distinct, without some knowledge of e.g. discriminant of an algebraic number field.

You can instead note that it contains $\mathbb Q(\sqrt D)$ and $\mathbb Q(i)$. These are both degree two, and distinct since one is real and the other not.

Good point, and this again works for $x^4-b$ in general (for $b>0$ at least), so there is really no reason to work with the special forms  $\sqrt{a\sqrt D}$.
